# Selenium Not able to click Dojo Element Object Link on WebPage

Tags: selenium-webdriver, hover, click

I have an application where I need hover on Menu Item and then I need to click on Link.I am able to hover but not able to click on below link even it is present and selenium also able to identify it.

I have tried below code for that :-

```
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 Thread.sleep(10000);
 action.moveToElement(hover_element).moveToElement(Element_To_Click).click().buil‌​d().perform();
 action.moveToElement(hover_element).build().perform(); 
 Thread.sleep(3000); driver.findElement(by2).click();
```

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            action.moveToElement(hover_element).moveToElement(Element_To_Click).click().build().perform();
            action.moveToElement(hover_element).build().perform();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(by2).click();

Comment: Please find above code which I have used for Hover and Click.

Comment: please paste the html source code

Comment: Html code for hover element  <div class="parentItem menuItemHover" id="CUS">Customer</div> .....Html code for click element  <span class="subMenuLabel moreSpanWidth">Customer Overview</span>

Comment: ok you want to click on customer overview which appears just after you hover over menu items right also please show me your by2

Comment: Taking in consideration that you are able to hover over the menu item and sub menu items are clearly visible try to use expected conditions before click like WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("locator to sub menu which you wnat to click")));

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see whether it works or not :

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(hover_element);
Thread.sleep(5000); 
action.perform();
action.moveToElement(Element_To_Click).click().perform();
```

Comment: No it is not working.It hover to the element on webpage but it is not clicking on the menuitem below.Tried the same code as above.